# hey anyone know how to post message on a Facebook group that I don't a the group Admin?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i can send to my groups but cant to groups that I don't the Admin
im using Facebook APi
this is my code

```
import requests

def post_to_facebook_group(group_id, access_token, message):
    url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/%7Bgroup_id%7D/feed"
    params = {
        "access_token": access_token,
        "message": message
    }
    response = requests.post(url, params=params)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Post successfully created!")
    else:
        print("An error occurred while creating the post.")
        print(f"Response: {response.json()}")

Replace the placeholders with your own values
group_id = ""
access_token = ""
message = "Hello, World!"

post_to_facebook_group(group_id, access_token, message)
```

I'm trying to post in a group I don't the manage

Comment: An admin has to add the app to the group.

Comment: how he can add it ? and if i want to add at too Open group i can ?

Comment: Maybe read the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/groups-api/overview . Which under "App Installation" links to https://www.facebook.com/help/261149227954100 . Yes an admin of the Open group can add the app.

Comment: @WizKid I am trying to get the feed of a public group on facebook. I am able to get the feed of groups I am an admin of but cant seem to get it for the public group im not a part of. Do you know if an admin needs to add the app for me to get the feed of the group? Also, fyi the app is not verified yet.